# reading JSON with custom schema - pyspark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark

When reading the JSON with custom schema it gives me all `NULL` values. I know the reason why (because the actual data type does not match the custom schema type) but I dont know how to fix it (except reading it `with open` method). I want to you spark to read not JSON module.

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("JSON test") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
schema = StructType([StructField("_links", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), StringType()))),
                         StructField("identifier", StringType()),
                         StructField("enabled", BooleanType()),
                         StructField("family", StringType()),
                         StructField("categories", ArrayType(StringType())),
                         StructField("groups", ArrayType(StringType())),
                         StructField("parent", StringType()),
                         StructField("values", MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(MapType(StringType(), StringType())))),
                         StructField("created", StringType()),
                         StructField("updated", StringType()),
                         StructField("associations", MapType(StringType(), MapType(StringType(), ArrayType(StringType())))),
                         StructField("quantified_associations", MapType(StringType(), IntegerType())),
                         StructField("metadata", MapType(StringType(), StringType()))])
    
df = spark.read.format("json") \
            .schema(schema) \
            .load(f'/mnt/bronze/products/**/*.json')
df.display()
```

JSON  original strcutre:

```
root
 |-- _embedded: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- items: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _links: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- self: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- associations: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ERP_PIM: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- product_models: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- categories: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- created: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- enabled: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- family: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- groups: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- identifier: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- metadata: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- workflow_status: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- parent: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- updated: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- values: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Contrex_table: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- data: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- locale: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- scope: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- UFI_Table: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |-- _links: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- first: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- next: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- self: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- href: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first pass of the data I would suggest reading the data in it's original format eg if booleans are in the json like `{"enabled" : "true"}`, I would read that psuedo-boolean value as a string (so change your `BooleanType()` to `StringType()`) and then later cast it to a Boolean in a subsequent step after it's been successfully read in.

This should stop the `null` values as spark throws out the value if there's a datatype mismatch

Comment: unfortunately no, it does not work! I still get `null` values except `_links`. I have updated the post with original JSON structure